# aligning the buttons in the div

Tags: css

I have the issue where I want to show only 2 link buttons in the middle of blue div next to the image.

I want something like this

```
link1   {space} link2
{space}
link3    {space} link 4
```

currently it is like this

```
link1
link2
link3
link4
```

here is my code
 HTML

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
<div class="my-background">
    <div class="div1" style="float:left;"> </div>

        <span class="buttons">
         <a class="buttonStyling" href="test.com"><b>Link 1</b></a>
        <a class="buttonStyling" href="test.com"><b>Link 2</b> </a>
         <a class="buttonStyling" href="test.com"><b>Link 3</b> </a>
        <a class="buttonStyling" href="test.com"><b>Link 4</b> </a>
        </span>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.my-background{
    background-color: #8af0fc;
    height: 204px;
}
.div1 {
    height: 205px;
    background:  url(http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/lightbox2/horses.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 435px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: futura, arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    width:256px;
    margin-bottom: -20%;
}
.buttons .buttonStyling{

    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 35%;
    float:right;

}

.buttonStyling {

    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 33%, rgba(225, 225, 225, 1) 100%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(225, 225, 225, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 33%, rgba(225, 225, 225, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 33%, rgba(225, 225, 225, 1) 100%);     color: #333;
}
```

here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cUWn8/4/

Comment: Do you want the buttons in the four corners?  Do you want them with a specific spacing between them centered in the middle of the div area?

Comment: What is your plan for div1? right now it just creates a pointless margin, is it supposed to contain the buttons?  You have enough extra styling that it's not clear what your actual intent is.

Comment: I'm still confused at what you want, image on the left, blue box on the right and 2 bottons in the blue with 2 buttons on the image?  Be a little more specific about how you want the final layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get rid of the floats
2. Add display: inline-block
3. Add margins for the spacing you need

Use this css

```
.buttons .buttonStyling{

    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 35%;
   margin: 0 50px 50px 0; //or however much space you want
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/h3w3N/) with the above changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cUWn8/5/

Basically, don't carpet-bomb everything with `float` and instead only apply it to the even buttons, that will produce the positioning you described.  To get the vertical space between (1 and 2) and (3 and 4), add `margin-top` to buttons after #2.  Also, all buttons need to be `display: inline-block`.

The key CSS changes are:

```
.buttons .buttonStyling { display: inline-block; }
.buttonStyling:nth-of-type(even) { float: right; }
.buttonStyling:nth-of-type(2) ~ .buttonStyling{ margin-top: 50px; }
```

plus the removal of existing `float` property on `.buttons .buttonStyling` and inline on `div1`.

Answer (score 0):

Clean it up and set max widths on your .buttons span, Give this a try: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OldCode101/cUWn8/6/)